# Add a record to the database without refreshing

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to add a record dynamically.
When I insert action = "add.php" for my form, the addition is accomplished by displaying a message after refreshing.
I want to add this addition without refreshing dynamically.

Also, for the ID of my games, I want that when I delete a record, for the ID to be decremented or removed.  So that, when I add a game again, it uses the next ID available, not keeps on incrementing, like it is happeneing with me now.

If I take off add.php from action, nothing happens and the game isn't added. 
My question is, where is this script broken? Or if add.php is not functioning right?

Here is my index.php and add.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
     <title>title</title>
</head>
 <body>
 <?php
include("dbconfig.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM games";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  echo "<p class=\"p" .$record['ID']. "\"></br> Game ID: " .$record['ID']. "</br> Game Name: " .$record['Name'].
  "<br /> Game Type: ".$record['Type']. "<br /> Rating: ".$record['Rating']."<br />  Year Released: ".$record['Release Year']."<br /> <br />" ?>
 <a href="#" id="<?php echo $record["ID"]; ?>" class="deletebutton"><img  src="trash.png" alt="delete"/> </a></p>
<?php
 }
?>

 <form name="add" id ="add" action=""  method="post">
 <input class ="gameID" type="hidden" id="ID" name="ID" value = " ' .$record['ID'] . ' " />
 <b>Game Name: </b> <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size=70>
 <b>Game Type:</b> <input type="text" id="type" name="type" size=40>
 <b>Rating: </b> <input type="number"  id="score"  name="score" min="1.0" max="10.0"  step ="0.1"/>
 <b>Year Released: </b> <input type="number"  min="1900" max="2011" id="Yreleased" name="Yreleased" value="1985" size=4>
 <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" id = "Submit" value="Add Game" class = "add games"></p>
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#add").submit(function(){


                        var name =    this['name'].value;
                        var type =    this['type'].value;
                        var rating =  this['score'].value;
                        var release = this['Yreleased'].value;
                        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&type=' + type + '&rating=' + rating + '&release=' + release;

                    if (name == '' || type == '' || rating == '' || release == ''){
                        alert("please enter some valid data for your game entry");
                    }else
                    $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "add.php",
                         data: dataString,
                         success: function(){
                           window.location.reload(true);
                          $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                          $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                         }
                    });

           return false;
        }

                                )});

        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.deletebutton").click(function(){
             var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
             var info = 'id=' + del_id;
             var parent = $(this).parent();
            if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this game? !..There is no Undo")){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "delete.php?" + info,

                    context: document.body,
                    success: function(){

                        $('.p'+del_id).html('deleted');
                        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    }
                });
            }
             return false;
     });
 });
 </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

### add.php

```
<?php
    require('dbconfig.php'); //we cannot continue without this file, thats why using require instead of include

    if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {

    $name=addslashes($_POST['name']);
    $type=addslashes(($_POST['type']));
    $rating=addslashes($_POST['rating']);
    $release=addslashes($_POST['release']);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `games` (`Name`,`Type`,`Rating`,`Release Year`)  VALUES ("'.$name.'", "'.$type.'", "'.$rating.'", "'.$release.'")'; 
    mysql_query( $sql);
    if(!mysql_errno())
    echo " your game has been added to the list of games. ";
    }
?>
```

Comment: read more about ajax, this is what ajax does.

Comment: i did james and i tried to add a record without refreshing but i am doing something wrong, not sure how to pass the arguments from the form and add them to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code is currently trying to do is the right principle: you are trying to trap the submit event on the form, make your Ajax request instead, and then cancel the default submit.

The reason it doesn't work is this line:

```
$("add games").Submit(function(){
```

".submit()" should have a lowercase "s", and the selector you are using, "add games", is not going to return any elements because it looks for elements with the tag name "games" that are descendents of elements with tag name "add".

What you want to do is fix the case of the "s", and select your element by id, which you do with "#yourid". Your form name has the id "add", so do this:

```
$("#add").submit(function(){
```

Also both your document.ready and your submit handler functions have an extra pair of `{}` curly braces around their bodies so you should delete those:

```
$("#add").submit(function(){
   {                           // <- delete this {
      /*function body code*/
   }                           // <- delete this }
});
```

Also you are including the jquery.js script twice - once is enough. And you don't need two document.ready handlers, you can combine them into a single one (though you *can* have more than one and that shouldn't cause a problem).

(There may be some other issues, but try this first and get back to us.)

**UPDATE:** After the other fixes, I suspect the problem is now in your PHP, in the line:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
```

I don't know PHP, but I assume this is checking for a request parameter called 'Submit' that you are not setting in your JS (it was the name of your submit button and would've been set for a "standard", non-Ajax submit, but it won't be included in your Ajax request). Try changing that line to use a request parameter that you are setting, like:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
```

Then, even if you don't seem to get a response in the browser, check your database to see if records are being added.

Comment: thank you nnnnn, i changed the code as you said, and changed action = add.php to action ="" in the form .. it still does not add the record to the database or the page, but just reload with no changes after i press on add games. i edited my code to reflect the changes

Comment: Try the extra point I edited into my answer while you were editing your question: You've got two pairs of `{}` curly braces around the function bodies for your document.ready and your submit handler. You should have `$("#add").submit(function(){ /*code*/ });` but you've got `$("#add").submit(function(){ { /*code*/ } });` (with the second `{` on a new line and the corresponding closing `}` at the bottom of the block.) Same for document.ready.

Comment: thanks, i edited that and took the extra braces off. still the same issue but looks better and getting used to a more neat code.

Comment: @nnnnnn: do those extra braces matter in case all his code is in that same block :)?

Comment: @Rohan: You're right. I don't know what I was thinking, but the extra braces shouldn't actually cause a problem. (But they do unnecessarily complicate the code which doesn't help when trying to figure out which part is broken.) Perhaps Brian's answer is the last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: nnnnn : i edited the code and the alert message for checking datastring  if (name == '' || type == '' || rating == '' || release == ''){
                        alert("please enter some valid data for your game entry");   is functioning and i can see the alert. but if i press on add game now nothing happens when i fill the form.. not even refreshing

Comment: I think you've now removed the syntax errors from your JavaScript and so it doesn't refresh because you are (correctly) cancelling the non-Ajax form submit - which is what you want. I suspect the new problem is in your PHP: the line `if(isset($_POST['Submit']))` is checking for a request parameter called 'Submit' that you are not setting. Try changing it to `if(isset($_POST['name']))` because you _are_ setting the 'name' parameter. Then, even if you don't seem to get a response in the browser, check your database to see if records are being added.

Comment: @nnnnn actually you are right man. i am almost there. 
i changed it to  if(isset($_POST['name'])) and now adding is not doing on the web page but it is actually adding it to the database 
but look how it looks in the database because i pass name as a parameter
i am not sure how to fix 2 things now to submit this task 
1- how to make the webpage add it dynamically and show it because the db addition is working
2- what parameter to pass in order to have record look right

Game ID: 22
Game Name: NHL 12type=sportsrating=9year released=2011
Game Type:
Rating: 0
Year Released: 0

Comment: You need to separate the parameters in the query string with ampersands, like this: `var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&type=' + type + '&rating=' + rating + '&year released=' + release;` - otherwise what you have is a single parameter called 'name' with the rest of the string as its value.

Comment: As far as refreshing the page after inserting the record, you could just reload the whole page from index.php. Or within your `$.ajax()` success function append a new paragraph after the existing paragraphs, in which case your add.php should return the ID of the newly added record so that it is available if the user clicks delete - or return the appropriate HTML markup for the new record (which would include the ID). I think we've gone beyond what is reasonable for one question now that all your other problems are solved, but in any case I can't explain any further right now, I've got to go.

Comment: @nnnnn
i edited the code my friend. everything is working :) :)
i am not sure how to thank you and thank everyone who commented. i cant even add a rep point because i have 10 posts only.. but all ur feedback is highly appreciated and really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Make a few changes:

```
$("add games").submit(function(){ }); -> $(".add games").Submit(function(){});
```

or

```
$("#add").submit(function(){}); or    $("#add").click(function(){ //run your ajax script here});
```

as for the id issue, MySQl will keep incrementing the id and if you delete one, it won't decrement it. May I know why you want the ids in order?

Editing again: (Use json.js)

```
here is another workaround:

var postdata = new Object();
postdata.name = value;
postdata.type = value;
postdata.rating = value;
//and so on

$.ajax({ 
        url: 'your url', 
        type: "POST", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //add this
        data: JSON.stringify(postdata), //another change
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data, st) { 
            if (st == "success") { 
                alert('Data Added');
            } 
        }, 
        error: function() { 
            alert("Failed!"); 
        } 
    });
```

Comment: thanks rohan 
i changed the code to reflect the second line u suggested. it is still not adding the record.. as for the IDs it is because when i delete record 1, 2 and 3 for example, and try to add a game, it will add with ID 4 instead of 1 ... this ID thing is a minor issue for now ... i just want the add to work and learn from it. this website is simply the best. i just started coding but it gave me a lot in 2 days. thanks for your feedback it is appreciated.

Comment: in case your table gets empty, like you mentioned in your comment, you can restart from 1 by resetting the ID to 1. But this won't happen all the time :)

Comment: thanks rohan for the link. it looks really helpful. 
i tried the json way but it did not change anything for me. check the edited code after brians addition and let me know ur suggestion . thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the problems everyone else helped with, your form is still submitting because of this line:

```
if (id =='' || name == '' || type == '' || rating == '' || release == ''){
```

You did not define `id` in the code above it.  This is causing the function to throw an exception before `return false` is called.  You need to either remove `id =='' ||` from your if-statement or define it in your function.

As a side note, I see that you are pulling data from the form using the following:

```
var name = $("#name").val();
var type = $("#type").val();
```

Inside the submit handler, `this` is the form object, meaning you can access form fields by name.  I would recommend using the following properties:

```
var name = this['name'].value,
    type = this['type'].value;
```

This way, you don't need IDs on your form fields and you could if necessary insert the same form multiple times in the document.

Also, you should be validating your form input.  A user could enter `"); DROP TABLE games;//` or `<script src='http://evil.com/bad.js'></script>` in any of your fields and really ruin your life.

Comment: thanks brian
i edited my code by adding this as u suggested. 
and i removed the id from the checking. now if i try to submit with empty inputs it gives me the alert message please enter some valid data. but if i press on add game it will not do anything and wont function .. you can check my edited code too.. thanks for the reply

Comment: Check your server log to see if add.php is getting executed.  It is possible that your PHP is failing.  You aren't doing anything to capture if the AJAX call fails.  I would recommend reading the jQuery ajax documentation for A) how to handle errors and B) passing data using a data object rather than a string.  Passing as a string is prone to errors.

Comment: thank you for thelp , i will do that for sure.. it is just my first task to train on this on my own and it is my first project
now i changed the parameter i pass in the add.php from submit to if(isset($_POST['name'])) and it is working by adding it to the db but not the web page, and the record is not being loaded on screen to reflect addition .. i will edit my code now

Comment: I'm just curious...obviously you want to sanitize the input, but what are the chances of the user guessing the table name and knowing that you don't sanitize? I guess you wouldn't want to name your table 'users' just in case.

Comment: @Ian There is a whole profession, industry, [StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com) devoted to finding, fixing, and avoiding these types of vulnerabilities.  Passing in a quote character and seeing it fail will tell you that the data isn't sanitized.  Another error may disclose table/column names.  Using a name other than 'users' is called security through obscurity and it a well known bad practice.